# how to permit certain entities api to all users in jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jhipster

I am using jhipster 4.6.2 and Angular 1+

I want this questions entity to be permitted to all users.After searching in the internet, i came to know that adding the below lines in SecurityConfiguration.java. But after adding these lines, API's are hit in the backend. But getting this  error in the logs.

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'username' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?**

```
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/questions").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/questions/id").permitAll()
```

how can i achieve this? I want few more entites to be permitted to all users without login.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#authorize-requests): Each matcher is considered in the order they were declared. Also you should keep authenticated requirement or /api/**

Try this:

```
    .antMatchers("/api/questions").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/questions/id").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")..authenticated()
```